# Убрать порт 8080 с url

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, php-nginx

Всем привет, нужна помощь такого характера. Развернул докер, клонил отсюда https://github.com/atillay/docker-lemp. 
вот конфиги nginx

```
http {
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name myapp.laravel;
    root /var/www/public/myapp.laravel/public/;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}



server_tokens off;
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 15;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
access_log off;
error_log off;
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
open_file_cache max=100;
 }

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
  multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
   }

user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
daemon off;
```

Вопрос вот в чем, если ввести в адресную строку http://myapp.laravel, мне браузер выдает "Не удается получить доступ к сайту", если же ввести http://myapp.laravel:8080 то все гуд. Как убрать порт 8080 с ссылки? Заранее спасибо

Comment: `SERVER_PORT=8080` в файле .env.dist поменять на то что вам нужно

Comment: @KostaB. поменять порт не проблема, но мне нужно убрать этот порт с урла, что бы я заходил по адресу  http://myapp.laravel, а не по  http://myapp.laravel:8080

Comment: `php artisan serve --port=8080` поменять port на то что вам нужно

Comment: I updated the readme on the repo [https://github.com/atillay/docker-lemp#tent-use-a-virtual-host](https://github.com/atillay/docker-lemp#tent-use-a-virtual-host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как убрать порт 8080?

Поменять в файле `.env.dist` строку:

```
SERVER_PORT=8080
```

На то что вам нужно.

---

Если пройти по тому линку, который вы представили [docker-lemp](https://github.com/atillay/docker-lemp)

---

**UPD:**

Меняем порт на что нужно, вот так:

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

есть так же параметр `--host=0.0.0.0`, который подвязывает к другому адресу.